# How do I create a mapper from entity to dto, where dto is nested?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mapping

Two entities with corresponding dtos are given

entities:

```
class GalleryBlock(
    var images: List<Image?>,
    override val sortIndex: Int = 0,
) : ArticleBlock(sortIndex)

class Image(
    var url: String,
    var imageSize: ImageSize,
    override var id: Long,
    override var lastModified: Date,
    override var lastModifiedBy: String? = null ) : DBEntity

enum class ImageSize {
    SMALL,
    MEDIUM,
    LARGE, }
```

dtos

```
data class GalleryBlockDto(
    var images: List<ImageDto>,
    override val sortIndex: Int,
) : ArticleBlockDto

data class ImageDto(
    var id: Long,
    var url: String,
    var imageSize: ImageSize,
)
```

for the mapping I have written an interface Mapper

```
interface Mapper<E, D> {
    fun fromEntity(entity: E): D
}
```

for the mapping from class Image to ImageDto I have create a class ImageMapper

```
@Component
class ImageMapper: Mapper<Image, ImageDto> {
    override fun fromEntity(entity: Image): ImageDto {
        return ImageDto(entity.id, entity.url, entity.imageSize)
    }
}
```

when mapping the GalleryBlock I did the same but I get a type mismatch.

```
@Component
class GalleryBlockMapper: Mapper<GalleryBlock, GalleryBlockDto> {
    override fun fromEntity(entity: GalleryBlock): GalleryBlockDto {
        val images = entity.images
        val sortIndex = entity.sortIndex
        return GalleryBlockDto(images, sortIndex)
    }
}
```

is my approach correct? and how do I get the type mismatch fixed without changing the fields of Dto and entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GalleryBlockMapper you pass Image instances to the GalleryBlockDto. But ImageDto instances are needed. The ImageMapper needs to be injected into the GalleryBlockMapper, so the images can be mapped.

```
@Component
class GalleryBlockMapper(private val imageMapper: ImageMapper): Mapper<GalleryBlock, GalleryBlockDto> {
    override fun fromEntity(entity: GalleryBlock): GalleryBlockDto {
        val images = entity.images.map { imageMapper.fromEntity(it) }
        val sortIndex = entity.sortIndex
        return GalleryBlockDto(images, sortIndex)
    }
}
```